# Switch to file bookmark silently

Tags: bookmarks

I created a bookmark-file bookmark, with [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus). Now when I open it using `C-u C-x j y` I need to answer 3 questions:

```
Jump to bookmark-file bookmark (test): <enter>
SWITCH to new bookmark file, instead of just adding it? (y or n) y
Save current bookmarks before loading? (y or n) y
```

How to get rid of these questions and just silently load the file answering `y` everywhere?

Comment: Are you talking about Emacs' built-in Bookmarks? And what is `C-x j`? Vanilla Emacs doesn't have such key binding.

Comment: @xuchunyang: OP is using Bookmark+, where `C-x j y` is bound, by default, to `bmkp-bookmark-file-jump`, which loads a bookmark file.

Answer (score 1):

Use a command such as this one, binding it to a key:

```el
(defun my-bookmark-file-switch (bookmark)
  "Prompt for a bookmark-file BOOKMARK and switch to that bookmark file."
  (interactive
   (let ((alist  (bmkp-bookmark-file-alist-only)))
     (list (bmkp-read-bookmark-for-type "bookmark-file" alist nil nil
                                        'bmkp-bookmark-file-history))))
  (let ((file  (bookmark-prop-get bookmark 'bookmark-file)))
    (bookmark-load file t 'save)))
```

This command first saves the current bookmark list to the current bookmark file, before switching to the new bookmark file.  If you do not want that behavior (you want to just abandon any unsaved changes to the current bookmark list) then replace `save` in this code with just `t`.

But as always, *back up your current bookmark file* before trying this or other new bookmark code.

---

UPDATE:

I've now added these two commands to Bookmark+: **`bmkp-bookmark-file-load-jump`**, **`bmkp-bookmark-file-switch-jump`**  They are like `bmkp-bookmark-file-jump` (`C-x j y`), but they do not prompt for prior saving or confirmation.  The second of these is what you requested.

Comment: "I've now added these two commands to Bookmark+" - where can I see the new file? git repository is not modified

Comment: Your function works, but the contents of the bookmarks list is not updated. I need to close the list and load it again manually using `bookmark-bmenu-list`

Comment: No, you don't need to do that - just hit `g`. And `bmkp-bookmark-file-switch-jump` does that automatically. Why didn't you update [`bookmark+-1.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/bookmark%2b-1.el)?

Comment: Tried your function. It works, but still asks a question: "Jump to bookmark-file bookmark (teat):" Is it possible to get rid of this as well?

Comment: No. It's asking you which bookmark-file bookmark you want to use, that is, which bookmark file you want to switch to. The default is the last one you used, other than the current one. If that's what you want then just hit `RET`.

Comment: "It's asking you which bookmark-file bookmark you want to use" - I want to use the currently selected file. Why hit enter again? It's a useless action.

Comment: Is it possible not to hit Enter and proceed automatically?